# jsp Custom Tag: doAfterBody method is not invoked

Tags: java, jsp, jboss7.x, custom-tags

The below code is not working in JBoss 7. I have also tested it in Tomcat 7.

The root cause is constructor and doAfterBody method is not invoked for `<xml>` tag. Even though it is getting invoked for parent tag `<xslt>`.

When child tag `<xml>` is moved outside `<xslt>` then it works. That means child tag is not recognised.

.tld file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<taglib>
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
  <short-name>xx</short-name>
  <uri></uri>

  <tag>
    <name>xml</name>
    <tag-class>com.mycompany.XsltXmlTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>tagdependent</body-content>
  </tag>

  <tag>
    <name>xslt</name>
    <tag-class>com.mycompany.XsltTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>tagdependent</body-content>
  </tag>

</taglib>
```

tag class for `<xml>` tag:

```
public class XsltXmlTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    public XsltXmlTag() {
        log("constructor not invoked.");
    }

    public int doAfterBody() throws JspException {
        log("this method is not invoked.");
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="xmlx.tld" prefix="x"%>

...

<x:xslt media="html">
    <x:xml>
        <?xml version="1.0" ?>
        ...
    </x:xml>

    ...
</x:xslt>
```

it is working in Tomcat 7, after setting `<body-content>` to jsp instead of tagdependent. But, in JBoss 7, tld validation is failing for `<body-content>jsp</body-content>`

In JBoss 7, it works with `<body-content>scriptless</body-content>`. But, I have scripts such as `<%= contextPath%>` and `<jsp:expression>` inside `<xml>` tag.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

child tag `<xml>` is processed after setting `<body-content>` to scriptless. And, have replaced scripts inside `<xml>` tag with custom tags.